# I'm trying to figure out which functions from one C library are being used by C project. Does anyone have a simple solution?

Tags: c++, c

To be specific, I want to know which function/types in libpri and being used in the Asterisk project. I'm not traditionally a C programmer, but I know some basic stuff because I took a class in college.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your code compiles... comment out the line that imports the library in question (i.e. comment out the line that imports libpri). Then try to compile the code. The functions that the compiler says it can't find/identify are the ones being used from the library.

Answer (score 3):

if you statically import the library you can remove the lib reference from the linker and see which symbols are undefined